# Multiple Row Param String to Single Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that mimics the MYSQL 'UPSERT' command. ie. insert if new / update existing if record exists.

I wish to keep the number of calls to SQL Server to an absolute minimum ie. 1

So can I pass an param string to a stored procedure (SP_MAIN) and in this stored procedure then call my 'UPSERT' stored procedure for every unique table row that is passed as a param to SP_MAIN...?
If so, can anyone illustrate with a simple example please..?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far? Any code samples with test data would be helpful also.

Comment: I would do some reading on a merge statement if I were you - that is what handles upserts in sql server: [merge](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/)

Comment: This post is not specifically for info. on UPSERT - I have done this .. I need qulification on the top level (SP_MAIN) stored procedure and its construction. I have no sample code... but in its simplest form..

SP_MAIN 1,A,2,B,3,C,4,D,5,E

where 1,2,3,4,5 are the primary keys for each row I wish to insert/update...

Comment: if you don't know the number of params you want to pass in, you could pass either a comma-separated string of row IDs, and then create a routine to extract each value, and run the main procedure in a loop. Or look at using a table variable as a parameter, and loop through that.

Comment: ADyson...<if you don't know the number of params you want to pass in, you could pass either a comma-separated string of row IDs, and then create a routine to extract each value, and run the main procedure in a loop>..
This is pretty much what I had in mind... but creating the routine to extract the values within the SP is where I could use some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the merge statements. See a sample below: The table to be updated is dbo.Table. We use Table Valued Parameter to update/insert the data. The merge statement is within a stored procedure

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Table]
(
    PrimaryKey INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
    ,Column1    INT NOT NULL
    ,Column2    INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.[TableTVP] AS TABLE (
    PrimaryKey INT NULL
    ,Column1    INT NULL
    ,Column2    INT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CRUD_Table
    @TableTVP   dbo.TableTVP READONLY
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @OutPut TABLE (Action  VARCHAR(10) NULL,EntityKey INT NULL)

MERGE dbo.[Table] AS TARGET
USING (SELECT
        PrimaryKey
        ,Column1
        ,Column2
        ,BINARY_CHECKSUM (Column1, Column2) as DataCheckSum
    FROM
        @TableTVP) AS SOURCE ON SOURCE.PrimaryKey = TARGET.PrimaryKey
    WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE.DataCheckSum <> BINARY_CHECKSUM (TARGET.Column1, TARGET.Column2) THEN
        UPDATE SET
            Column1 = SOURCE.Column1
            ,Column2 = SOURCE.Column2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
            Column1
            ,Column2
        )
        VALUES (
            SOURCE.Column1
            ,SOURCE.Column2
        )
    OUTPUT $action as [Action] 
        ,CASE WHEN $action IN ('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN Inserted.PrimaryKey ELSE Deleted.PrimaryKey END as [EntityKey] INTO @OutPut;
SELECT Action,EntityKey FROM  @OutPut
GO